# Why does the regular delete operator work when the array delete operator should be required?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, clang

I recently discovered that a lot places in our code were doing something like this:

```
int * int_array = new int[1000];

// ... do things with int_array

delete int_array;
```

The problem of course is that it should be using the `delete []` operator, not the regular `delete` operator.

The mystery is: This code has been working for literally years, when compiled by Visual Studio 2003 and 2005 on Windows, and GCC / clang on OS X. Why hasn't this caused things to go terribly wrong before now?

As I understand it, we're telling the compiler to deallocate memory the "wrong" way, and usually if you do that, something terrible happens and your program crashes. Why isn't this happening for us? Do modern compilers automatically "do the right thing" for you, or enough of the right thing that it doesn't matter for basic types, or something else? I can't accept that we simply got lucky, as this code has been in use for years, by thousands of customers under multiple different operating systems.

Note that I'm NOT asking for an excuse to do things wrong, just trying to understand why we aren't in trouble for doing things wrong. :)

Comment: Undefined behaviour is undefined.

Comment: Most of software out there contains lot of defects and undefined behaviors that do not manifest themselves as actual externally observable issues.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the nature of undefined behavior -- it might do exactly what you intended it to do. The problem is, with the next version of the compiler, operating system, library, or CPU ... it might do something completely different.

Most likely, you're getting away with it for two reasons:

1. `int` doesn't have a destructor. So the failure to correctly destroy each element in the array has no consequences.
2. On this platform, `new` and `new[]` use the same allocator. So you're not returning a block to the wrong allocator.

Comment: This is spot on. Having looked at the source for the global new / delete in [gcc's libstdc++](https://github.com/mirrors/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/libsupc%2B%2B/del_opv.cc) and [clang's libc++](http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/libcxx/trunk/src/new.cpp), it would seem that `delete []` simply calls `delete` in these implementations.

Answer (score 3):

Let's run through what happens, step by step (but we'll ignore exceptions):

```
int *foo = new int[100];
```

This allocates `100*sizeof(int)` bytes of memory and calls `int::int()` 100 times, once for each element in the array.

Since `int` is a builtin type, it has a trivial constructor (i.e, it does nothing).

Now, how about:

```
delete foo;
```

This will call `int::~int()` on the address pointed to by `foo`, and then delete the memory pointed to by `foo`. Again, since `int` is a built-in type, it has a trivial destructor.

Compare this to:

```
delete [] foo;
```

which will call `int::~int()` for each of the items in the array pointed to by `foo` and then delete the memory pointed to by foo.

The basic difference here is that elements 1..99 don't get destructed. For `int` that's not a problem, and that's probably why your existing code works. For arrays of objects that have a real destructor, you'll see a lot more misbehavior.

P.S.  Most implementations will delete the whole block of memory pointed to by `foo` if you write `delete foo;` even if you allocated it with array-new - but you would be foolish to count on that.

Comment: I didn't see this answer earlier. It's the clearest explanation so far.

Answer (score 1):

This does not work. deleting arrays without `[]` will leak memory. It'll affect the performance if your application runs for long time. For short lived programs there will be no issue.

Another thing to note is `delete` will destroy all the memory which were allocated by `new`.  If you have allocated an array by `new` (not `new []`) you can use `delete` to destroy it`.

Comment: @bikeshedder see the second paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

That will not cause the program to crash, but you will leak `999 * sizeof(int)` bytes of memory each time you do that.

Comment: Why isn't it `1000 * sizeof(int)`?

Comment: I would assume that is because you destroy the first element in the array. But not the rest.

Comment: I don't think you can, in general, make this claim. Many implementations will release the contiguous block of memory, as in a call to `free`. Otherwise, I think a crash is more likely than a leak.

Answer (score 1):

The regular `delete` operator may actually free all the memory from the array, depending on the allocator, but the real problem is it won't ever run any destructors on the array elements.